# Q# Error: No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning" exists

Tags: programming, q#, machine-learning

I'm having trouble getting the namespace `Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning`.

Here is an example Q# code:

```
namespace Temp {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning;

    operation Hello () : Unit{
        Message("Hello");
    }
}
```

Here is the python script which drives the code:

```
import qsharp
from qsharp import Result
import json
import os
from Temp import Hello
Hello.simulate()
```

Here's the error that the VSCode terminal shows:

```
Preparing Q# environment...
fail: Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp.Workspace[0]
      QS6104: No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning" exists.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Temp import Hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Temp'
```

Here are my component versions:

```
>>> qsharp.component_versions()
{'iqsharp': LooseVersion ('0.11.2004.2825'), 'Jupyter Core': LooseVersion ('1.3.52077.0'), '.NET Runtime': LooseVersion ('.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'), 'qsharp': LooseVersion ('0.11.2004.2825')}
```

I've tried adding the package manually into my conda environment:

```
>>> qsharp.packages.add("Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning::0.11.2004.2825")
Adding package Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning::0.11.2004.2825.>>> qsharp.reload()
```

But that doesn't help.

Also, it's worth to note that there is no such problem when I try to do the same in a local Jupyter Notebook which is weird since they run in the same environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to actually add these two lines into your Python script:

```
qsharp.packages.add("Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning::0.11.2004.2825")
qsharp.reload()
```

This causes the packages to be loaded and available at runtime.

You need those two lines before you call `from Temp import Hello`, otherwise you will get the errors since you try to open the `Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning` namespace inside your `Temp` namespace.

Notice that you may still see an error message that says `No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning" exists` due to the behavior of `import qsharp` (see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/issues/171) for more details), but your code should then compile and run successfully anyway, in which case you can ignore that error message.

Comment: This solves it, I tried adding those two lines in my script before but didn't regard the flow of program. Thank-you. But isn't there supposed to be a permanent solution to calling this package directly? I don't understand why there needs to be an explicit addition of this package for every script.

Comment: It's not actually installing anything. It's just loading the package so that its contents are available. (Similar to an `import` statement in Python.) It's roughly the same behavior as in the Q# Jupyter notebook, where you would have to call `%package` for each package dependency each time you restart the kernel and re-execute the notebook.

Answer (score 1):

In VS code, you have to manually add the package in the .csproj file under Item Group:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning" Version="0.11.2006.403" />
```

or alternatively, you can also add it in the terminal:

```
dotnet add [project_name].csproj package Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning
```