# Q#/VS: No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.Canon" exists

Tags: programming, q#

I am trying to run a simple "Hello World" project in Q#, following [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-q-programming/). I have completed the following steps (Step #s from tutorial link):

- Step 1: Installed the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.4 Preview 1.0)
- Step 2: Installed Microsoft Quantum Development Kit
- Step 3: Created a Q# Project using the Q# Application Template

The resulting `Program.qs` file appears in vs:

```
namespace Quantum.QSharpHelloWorld {

    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;

    
    @EntryPoint()
    operation HelloQ () : Unit {
        Message("Hello quantum world!");
    }
}
```

The two namespaces I am trying to `open` show the red squiggly line, with the errors

> QS6104: No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.Canon" exists.
>
> QS6104: No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic" exists.

Additionally and likely the same root cause, the `@EntryPoint` annotation and `Message()` call fail:

> QS6005: No type with the name "EntryPoint" exists in any of the open namespaces.
>
> QS5022: No identifier with the name "Message" exists.

In the solution explorer for my projet `QSharpHelloWorld`, the Dependencies, Packages, and each of five packages (Microsoft.Quantum.CSharpGeneration, .EntryPointDriver, .QSharp.Core, .Runtime.Core, and .Standard) all have the yellow triangle warning indicating a problem.

The error is similar to the one in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12520/q-error-no-namespace-with-the-name-microsoft-quantum-machinelearning-exists), except I'm not using Python so the accepted answer is irrelevant.  I attempted to use the command suggested in [another answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12573/13421):

```
dotnet add QSharpHelloWorld.csproj package Microsoft.Quantum.CSharpGeneration
```

However, this failed with the following error, suggesting this is the wrong solution:

```
error: Error while performing Update for package 'Microsoft.Quantum.CSharpGeneration'. Cannot edit items in imported files -
error:   Item 'PackageReference' for 'Microsoft.Quantum.CSharpGeneration' in Imported file 'C:\[...]\.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.sdk\0.19.2109165653\Sdk\Sdk.props'.
```

I can't find any other obvious/easy menu options or fixes for this.  Other questions I've found here on SE all seem to be related to Python integration, not using Visual Studio.  I have the feeling I'm missing something trivial and obvious. Can anyone suggest additional steps I can take?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67831975/how-do-i-get-hellow-quantum-world-to-run-in-visual-studio-2019 looks like a similar issue, and has several recommendations on restoring NuGet packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@Maria Mykhailova](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/2879/mariia-mykhailova) who pointed me to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67831975/how-do-i-get-hellow-quantum-world-to-run-in-visual-studio-2019) with similar symptoms.  This comment (lightly edited) in one of the answers was helpful:

> Then there is something broken with your local NuGet cache. Empty it by removing everything inside the packages folder and then run the command dotnet restore again.

While I didn't "remove everything" I did remove the five problematic packages, which enabled the program to execute following a restore.

I still had the "red squiggly" symptom in the VS editor, but [closing and reopening Visual Studio](https://youtu.be/5UT8RkSmN4k) seemed to resolve these as well.